# Why is tint2 blank in Openbox but not in Unity/Gnome Shell

Tags: 13.04, openbox, tint2

I'm playing around with tint2 and openbox. First all went fine, but suddenly there are no icons, systray etc. shown in tint2. Just a black panel. But only in opebnox. When starting tint2 in Gnome or Unity, all icons are there.
When starting tint2 in openbox from terminal, I got the following message(s):

```
tint2 : not icon swallow
```

What does that mean and how can I solve this?

Btw: I'm using Ubuntu 13.04.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have a icon that is buggy see [this](http://code.google.com/p/tint2/issues/detail?id=141) bug report with same error. Do you have Skype? It seems that the Skype icon/openbox/tint2 combination doesn't work all of the time, try a `pkill tint2&&tint2`, and see if that fixes it. If it does, you may have to live with it, or get a different dock-app, the bug been open for 4 years, and doesn't look like it got fixed.